# How to register application class in manifest file?

Tags: android, xml, manifest

How to register my application class in my android manifest?  I have looked at many tutorials online and still can not get it right. My application class is called `Monitor.java`. How do I register it in the Manifest file code below?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="xyz"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service
        android:name=".AudioService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="audioservice" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Editor"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.project.EDITOR" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: you forgot add "name" attribute in application tag..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
<application
        android:name="package.YourApplicationClass"  <--------
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="xyz"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: @Kevik: you can mark this answer as correct if you get solution

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
       android:label="@string/app_name" 
       android:name="Monitor">
```

See the good reference link below :

[How to use the Application object of Android](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android)

Thanks.

Comment: i will check out that link

Comment: @Kevik you will get good example of `Application class` with all required details with this given link. Thanks.

Comment: For sharing the link +1

Answer (score 3):

Simple, put `android:name` attribute with your application class name in `<application />` tag of Application's **Manifest.xml**

```
<application
 android:name=".Monitor"
   .... >
```

**Update:**

**Application Class:**

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own
>       implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which
>       will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

More info look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already have application class inside - starting with `<application`. If you have a custom class (that extends `Application`) in your code and want it to start - put

```
android:name=".Monitor" (or full path like com.something.app.Monitor)
```

after `<application` tag (the same process as you would add an activity).

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `android:name=".Monitor"` attribute to the `application` tag (I presume that the Monitor.java class is located in the root of the application package). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

what confused me is 'android:name' shows up multiple times in the manifest file.  before creating an application class file, i had

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

after the 'activity' tag.

after creating the application file, everything in manifest file stays the same, except after 'application' tag, i add

```
android:name=".myApplicationClass"
```

my complete manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pixtas.com.nightout" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="pixtas.com.nightout.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="pixtas.com.nightout.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".myApplicationClass" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="pixtas.com.nightout" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- replace @drawable/push_icon with your push icon identifier -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Monitor"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```