# Method in MyApplication never gets called

Tags: android

When I try to connect my Android APP to BlueTooth printer, the key method is never called. I followed the introduction of SDK:

1. Add permission
2. Init SDK in Application.onCreate()

   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       WPXMain.init(this);
   }

Wnen I run sample offered by SDK, I can see log:

03-29 11:15:25.399 10820-10820/com.wpx.printer.sample D/WPXMain: init

Here is the sample code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private List<Activity> list = new ArrayList<Activity>();

    public void addActivity(Activity activity) {}

    public void clearActivity(){
        for(Activity activity : list){
            if(activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()){
                activity.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        WPXMain.init(this);
    }

    public void exit() {
        clearActivity();

        System.exit(0);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

However, when I put that WPXMain.init(this); into my own MyApplication, I can neither see the init log, nor use any functionality of the SDK.

I guess it is because the WPXMain.init(this); in MyApplication is not called. Because if it's called, I should see the init log. Here is the init code in SDK:

```
public static void init(Application app) {
    init(app, false);
}

public static void init(Application app, boolean isBleModel) {
    WPXUtils.log(TAG, "init");
    WPXMain.Bean.wpx.filter.add("NP100");
    if(app != null) {
        WPXMain.Bean.wpx.isInit = true;
        WPXMain.Bean.wpx.isBleModel = isBleModel;
        WPXMain.Bean.wpx.app = app;
        if(isBleModel) {
            WPXMain.Bean.wpx.wblec = com.wpx.WPXBleControl.Bean.getInstance();
            WPXMain.Bean.wpx.wblec.init(app);
        } else {
            WPXMain.Bean.wpx.wbc = com.wpx.WPXBluetoothControl.Bean.getInstance();
            WPXMain.Bean.wpx.wbc.init(app);
            regReceiver();
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea? Thank you guys.

Comment: Have  you added application class in `Manifest`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register application class in my manifest file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949666/how-to-register-application-class-in-my-manifest-file)

Comment: @mallaudin Thank you dude, problem solved.

Comment: @ZhiKai Thank you Zhi Kai, problem solved

Comment: @Rangtian Glad it helped. Good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Manifest file mention your application name

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"

    >
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you soooooo much! I feel myself like a fool hahaha :D